# Sugar CRM - Performance Issues

Tags: php, iis-7, sugarcrm

I am trying to identify why my Sugar CRM sites are loading so slowly. I am hosting 22 sites on IIS, PHP version is 5.3.26, and my databases are on a seperate SQL Server 2008. The Web Server is running Windows 2008, IIS7, 10GB memory and has a Intel® Xeon® Processor E7-2870.

After profiling one of my databaes I have ruled out the issue to be data related as queries were consistently running in less than 1 second.

My hosting provider has confirmed that we have 100mb dedicated line to our web server. After running a speed test, I get around 70 mb down and 40 mb up, so I do not think this is a bandwidth issue.

I took a look at an offical 'Performance Tweaks' article, and made changes to the config_override.php as suggested, however this did not make a signifcant difference.

http://support.sugarcrm.com/04_Find_Answers/02KB/02Administration/100Troubleshooting/Common_Performance_Tweaks/

Something I have noticed is that there is an awful lot of PHP-CGI.EXE proccesses. As I look at the server now the average CPU consumption for one of these instances is 11%. I am not sure if this is something to be concerned about? The CPU Usage in Windows Task Manager looks very unstable.

To see if it was genernal PHP issue, I added a simple PHP script containing "echo (5 % 3)."\n";" - which was returned instantly.

To summarise web pages are taking on average 5 seconds to load and users are reporting the system as usable but slugglish.

Does anyone have any suggestions of how I might be able to speed up my application?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What does the page load time show at the bottom of the page in SugarCRM? If it shows something like 0-2s, but the page in reality takes much longer then look at adding Opcode caching such as APC or Memcache.

Comment: I've heard of people figuring out how to get IIS working well, but most do well by switching to Apache. You can still use MSSQL for your database.